# suffficient geolocation permission (cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, webview

get an error saying that the application does not have enough geolocation permissions

I observed that several Cordova applications for mobile devices use the Application System Webview. However, some mobile devices have it disabled and don't allow for location sharing.

What ought I to do in this circumstance?

I've set up the Cordova-Plugin-Geolocation 4.1.0 plugin.

additionally grant permissions in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a detailed answer from the little information you provided. But generally you need to request the users explicit permission to use features such as location, camera and storage. You can do this with the Cordova diagnostics plugins: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic
The documentation should tell you how.